# Java Tictactoe Problem For Checking a Draw Result

Tags: java

I'm doing simple TicTacToe Java Homework, only one left problem which is not having a proper way of getting a DRAW result. Pretty much done refining the normal condition winning steps for TicTacToe... Just the Draw result...

using a flag comes into my mind but don't have an idea of implement it in this code.

```
        if(check_axis.equals("XXX"))
        {
            System.out.println("Player 1 Wins !");
            end = 1;
            break;
        }else if(check_axis.equals("OOO")){
            System.out.println("Player 2 Wins !");
            end = 1;
            break;
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Drawn results !");
            end = 1;
            break;
        }
```

The full code -> https://textuploader.com/15vdu

Comment: -1 to this and all answers, and voting to close, because neither this question nor its answers make sense without referring to the code on textuploader.com. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to do it after your loop, if you found that noone has won.

```
String check_axis = "";
for(int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    ...
    if(check_axis.equals("XXX")) {
        ...
        end = 1;
        break;
    } else if(check_axis.equals("OOO")){
        ...
        end = 1;
        break;
    }
    // don't do it here!
}
if(end != 1) // if noone has won yet
{
    // check if the board is full (no empty spots left for a player to choose)
    // if it is full, then it is a tie
}
```

The reason you do not want to do this in the loop, is you need to check if none of the axes indicate a winner. Once you have checked all the axes for the winner and haven't found one, you can safely assume there is no winner.

Comment: Ah, I however has used the flag method, but like as u said, outside the loop which I implemented the flag on it